# How should I force TypeScript to understand that there won't be any null in this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm coming from JavaScript and learning TypeScript. I'm used to filter `null` from an array by using `.filter(x => x)`, however, with TypeScript it asks me to define that the array can contain `null`, which isn't true because `filter` removes all `null` from the array:

```
interface ILabels {
    alias: string
    publicKey: string
    lat: number
    long: number
}

const labels: ILabels[] = data.map((d) => {
  if (d.lat && d.long) {
    return {
      alias: d.alias || d.publicKey,
      publicKey: d.publicKey,
      lat: d.lat,
      long: d.long,
    };
  }
  return null;
}).filter((x) => x);
```

How should I force TypeScript to understand that there won't be any `null` in this array? The error TypeScript gives me is:

> TS2322: Type '({ alias: string; publicKey: string; lat: number; long: number; } | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'ILabels[]'.   Type '{ alias: string; publicKey: string; lat: number; long: number; } | null' is not assignable to type 'ILabels'.     Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ILabels'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use a user-defined type guard:

```js
function nonNull<T>(val: T | null): val is T {
  return val !== null;
}

const labels: ILabels[] = data.map((d) => {
  if (d.lat && d.long) {
    return {
      alias: d.alias || d.publicKey,
      publicKey: d.publicKey,
      lat: d.lat,
      long: d.long,
    };
  }
  return null;
}).filter(nonNull);
```

Or, with an arrow function:

```
const labels: ILabels[] = data.map((d) => {
  if (d.lat && d.long) {
    return {
      alias: d.alias || d.publicKey,
      publicKey: d.publicKey,
      lat: d.lat,
      long: d.long,
    };
  }
  return null;
}).filter(<T,>(x: T | null): x is T => x !== null);
```